# Updating Existing PHP echo

Tags: php, string

I've ran into a problem where I have to echo a string before getting the data that I want to also add in to the string. I need to keep the echo in the same place above the while statement so that the results from the while loop are displayed below the output statement.

Here's the code:

```
    $countTimes = 0;
    $jsonCheck_c = json_encode($json_c);

    output("font-weight: bold;", "Checklist (0 of " . $countTimes . " completed)");

    if(strlen($jsonCheck_c) > 20){
        while($searchChecklists){
            $checkPre = $json_c[0]['checkItems'][$countTimes]['name'];
            $jsonCheck_d = json_encode($checkPre);
            if($jsonCheck_d != "null"){
                $countTimes++;
                output("font-size: 12px;", $checkPre);
            }
            else {
                $searchChecklists = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Output simply echo's the string but with some parameters, I want to update $countTest in the output with the value when the while loop has finished.

Any idea would be great, cheers.

Comment: Where is the `$countTest` output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of echo'ing just collect in a variable and output later:

```
$jsonCheck_c = json_encode($json_c);
$output = array();

if(strlen($jsonCheck_c) > 20){
    while($searchChecklists){
        $checkPre = $json_c[0]['checkItems'][$countTimes]['name'];
        $jsonCheck_d = json_encode($checkPre);
        if($jsonCheck_d != "null"){
            $output[] = $checkPre;
        }
        else {
            $searchChecklists = false;
        }
    }
}

output("font-weight: bold;", "Checklist (0 of " . count($output) . " completed)");
foreach ($output as $line) {
    output("font-size: 12px;", $line);
}
```

This code can be slightly improved if you let your `output()` function return the result instead of `echo`'ing. In this case, you will avoid double cycle and instead collect all the results of `output()` within a string.